# AngularJS script is running twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a script that autoplays a video when a Bootstrap modal opens. I'm using a ng-click on the modal open form, which runs a jquery script withing the angularjs controller.

```
$scope.startVideo = function (id) {
    $(window).on('shown.bs.modal', function() { 
        console.log('Id nu is: '+id);
        var v = document.getElementById("player"+id);
        v.play();
        console.log('Now playing: player'+id);
    });
}
```

It works fine at first. But when I close the first modal (and stop the video), and fire the script again on another modal, the first video starts, and the second video starts. So now I have 2 video's playing.

The console is giving back: :

> Now playing: player1
>   Now playing: player1
>   
>   Now playing: player2

The part of the modal which might be interesting:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    {{video.subheader}}<br>
    <video id="player{{video.id}}" width="100%" height="100%" controls>
        <source src="{{video.videourl+video.ext}}" type="video/mp4></source>
    </video>
</div>

<!-- Popup modals below -->
<div id="videomodal{{video.id}}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">{{video.header}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                {{video.subheader}}<br>
                <video id="player{{video.id}}" width="100%" height="100%" controls>
                    <source src="{{video.videourl+video.ext}}" type="video/mp4"></source>
                </video>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why is the script running twice? I need it to run once when the modal opens. And when I stop the video, close the modal and open another modal, the other modal should start. Not both.

Comment: you're creating a new variable, `v` every time the modal opens. When you close it, the variable you made doesn't just disappear. You need to handle that

Comment: @Ronnie When I delete v at the end of the script like; delete v; it won't work.

Comment: just do `document.getElementById("player" + id).play();` If that doesn't solve it, create a fiddle for us that replicates the issue.

Comment: @Ronnie Something life can be so simple. That fixed it. Maybe file it as an anwer, so I can mark it as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

A quick guess would be that your event listeners aren't listening for shown.bs.modal from a specific modal but from any modal on the page. Assuming each modal has its own id (or data attribute or something) based on the id of the video (if they don't have ids you could use the jQuery :has selector - :has('#player'+id)  - or something along those lines)

```
$scope.startVideo = function (id) {
    $(window).on('shown.bs.modal', '<modal specific selector>', function() { 
        console.log('Id nu is: '+id);
        var v = document.getElementById("player"+id);
        v.play();
        console.log('Now playing: player'+id);
    });
}
```

Comment: The modals do indeed use their own id. Which I can then call again. Problem is it won't work with this selector. Now video's just won't play. $(window).on('shown.bs.modal', '#videomodal'+id, function() {

Comment: please post the html of one of the modals, and/or try the :has selector

Comment: HI I added the modal.

Comment: Sorry -- it looks right to me, not sure why it wouldn't work -- the shown.bs.modal is supposed to be sent to the element with class 'modal' which would bubble up and then get handled by the delegated handler.  That should correctly filter it to the modal that was shown based on the id selector you put of  '#videomodal'+id   - and then start playing (assuming the event handler is still getting installed).  I'm assuming you don't still have the 'delete v' line recommended in another comment since that would create issues.

Comment: Correct I don't use the delete v, since it won't work. But I still don't have an solotion which is quite anoying ;) Any other idea's?